# Using /YC and /MP together in a Visual Studio 10 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, winapi, precompiled-headers

I'm trying to get around the limitation of /YC and /MP being mutually exclusive. I'd like to leverage precompiled headers AND multi-process compilation.

My answer so far has been to create 2 projects instead of 1. The first is a pch generating library consisting of just an stdafx.h and stdafx.cpp. It generates the pch file with /YC set on the stdafx.cpp

That library generates the pch file successfully! As a side note, the pch library project also has /YU specified pointing to its stdafx.h and /Fp referencing the output pch file.

My second project is my main executable. It has /MP specified but does not have /YC specified for any file and does not contain an stdafx.h or stdafx.cpp. Instead I set the project's /YU to the stdafx.h of the pch library and /Fp to the pch generated by the pch library. I then set the pch library as a dependency of the exe project. I also set /FI on the exe project to forcibly include the stdafx.h from the pch library in each compilation unit.

My problem is that, while the pch library DOES generate the pch file and the exe project does seem to reference the generated pch file correctly, as soon as the exe project starts to build (after some pre-build steps unrelated to the pch), it DELETES the pch generated by the pch library. I imagine it's because it thinks, with /Fp is specified, that the project will generate that file even though there are no /YC's specified.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Am I missing a step. Is there a way to prevent the exe project from deleting my pch file before it starts building?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have written a short guide for this: https://leponceau.org/programming/2022-02-17-msvc-using-yc-and-mp-for-maximum-compile-speed-c.html

Answer (score 11):

Try this: [Does visual C++ check if it needs to re-generate its pch if I use /Yc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121700/does-visual-c-check-if-it-needs-to-re-generate-its-pch-if-i-use-yc)

You basically set /Yc for stdafx.cpp, and /Yu + /MP for all the other *.cpp files.

To set flags seperatelly for each file, right-click a cpp file on your Solution Explorer and select Properties.

Comment: What does it mean to set /MP on a single file? Will 8 cores compile that one file or does that just mean the file will be added to the list of files to be compiled by multiple processors?

Comment: "A source file is compiled when a process is available to compile it. If there are more files than processes, the first set of files is compiled by the available processes. The remaining files are processed when a process finishes handling a previous file and is available to work on one of the remaining files. " - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb385193.aspx. It's obviously 1 source file per process.

Comment: If you have 8 cores with hyperthreading, that'll make 16 virtual processors. That's 16 "effective processors". Visual Studio will run 1 process per effective processor. That will mean you'll have 16 source files compiled at the same time. That can be limited by setting the processMax argument, like so: /MP12. That'll limit the IDE to only run 12 processes at the same time, and thus compile 12 source files at the same time.

Comment: The documentation you posted cites that /Yc is "incompatible with the /MP option". I believe the reason is the potential race between stdafx.cpp being compiled simultaneously with a file that needs the pch to exist already. Have you ever successfully gotten this to work? Was it actually /MP? My experience was the compiler spat out a warning that /MP would be disabled due to the /Yc.

Comment: Yes I've gotten this to work successfully without any warnings. You should never combine /Yc and /MP. Luckily, there is /Yu which to my understanding uses an already existing pch file. So what you do is that you sacrifice /MP for stdafx.cpp and use /Yc to acquire a pch file which can be later used by all other source files with the /Yu flag. So /MP can be used everywhere but in stdafx.cpp. You do not have to worry about stdafx.cpp being compiled twice. It's compiled once in the beginning of the build process and then used by all other source files. At the end /Yc and /MP are working together.

Comment: I wasn't worried about stdafx.cpp being compiled twice. I was concerned it would not be compiled FIRST. So do all other compilation units wait for all those marked with /Yc (you can have more than 1) to complete?

Comment: According to my compilation output, yes. Even if it's more than 1 source file. Source files with the /Yc flag have the highest priority.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try when I have a chance

Comment: 1) I added this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006740/visual-studio-how-can-i-disable-a-command-line-option-for-a-certain-file
2) why isn't this answer accepted?

Comment: To be clear, the only _file_ that needs a distinct setting is `stdafx.cpp` or `pch.cpp`, which needs to be set to `/Yc`, while the _project_ can be set for both `/Yu` and `/MP`.